# C++ Functions with struct and vectors

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I just finished a program that reads a CSV file and outputs the rows using structs and vectors. My question involves these specific lines:

```
displayBid(bids[i]);

void displayBid(Bid bid)
{
    cout << bid.title << " | " << bid.amount << " | " << bid.fund << endl;
    return;
}
```

I am not sure if I am thinking about this correctly, but how is displayBid able to take in a vector as a parameter? The displayBid function takes in a struct called of Bid type. Originally I could not get the code to compile because I was trying displayBid(bid) and I got a scope error. I figured the displayBid function would need to take in a struct instead of a vector. Thanks.

Source:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

// FIXME (1): Reference the CSVParser library
#include "CSVparser.hpp"

using namespace std;



// forward declarations
double strToDouble(string str, char ch);

struct Bid
{
    string title;
    string fund;
    double amount;
    // Set default bid amount to 0.0
    Bid()
    {
        amount = 0.0;
    }
};



/**
 * Display the bid information
 *
 * @param bid struct containing the bid info
 */
void displayBid(Bid bid)
{
    cout << bid.title << " | " << bid.amount << " | " << bid.fund << endl;
    return;
}

/**
 * Prompt user for bid information
 *
 * @return Bid struct containing the bid info
 */
Bid getBid()
{
    Bid bid;

    cout << "Enter title: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, bid.title);

    cout << "Enter fund: ";
    cin >> bid.fund;

    cout << "Enter amount: ";
    cin.ignore();
    string strAmount;
    getline(cin, strAmount);
    bid.amount = strToDouble(strAmount, '$');

    return bid;
}

/**
 * Load a CSV file containing bids into a container
 *
 * @param csvPath the path to the CSV file to load
 * @return a container holding all the bids read
 */
vector<Bid> loadBids(string csvPath)
{
    // FIXME (2): Define a vector data structure to hold a collection of    bids.

    vector<Bid> bids;

    // initialize the CSV Parser using the given path
    csv::Parser file = csv::Parser(csvPath);

    // loop to read rows of a CSV file
    for (int i = 0; i < file.rowCount(); i++)
    {
        // FIXME (3): create a data structure to hold data from each row     and add to vector
        Bid bid;

        bid.title = file[i][0];
        bid.fund = file[i][8];
        //Convert to double and take out $
        bid.amount = strToDouble(file[i][4], '$');

        bids.push_back(bid);
    }
    return bids;
}

/**
 * Simple C function to convert a string to a double
 * after stripping out unwanted char
 *
 * credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24875936
 *
 * @param ch The character to strip out
 */
double strToDouble(string str, char ch)
{
    str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ch), str.end());
    return atof(str.c_str());
}

/**
 * The one and only main() method
 */
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // process command line arguments
    string csvPath;
    switch (argc)
    {
    case 2:
        csvPath = argv[1];
        break;
    default:
        csvPath = "eBid_Monthly_Sales_Dec_2016.csv";
    }

    // FIXME (4): Define a vector to hold all the bids
    vector<Bid> bids;





    // FIXME (7a): Define a timer variable
    clock_t timer;

    int choice = 0;
    while (choice != 9)
    {
        cout << "Menu:" << endl;
        cout << "  1. Enter a Bid" << endl;
        cout << "  2. Load Bids" << endl;
        cout << "  3. Display All Bids" << endl;
        cout << "  9. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Not currently implemented." << endl;

            break;
        case 2:
            // FIXME (7b): Initialize a timer variable before loading bids
            timer = clock();

            // FIXME (5): Complete the method call to load the bids
            bids = loadBids(csvPath);

            // FIXME (7c): Calculate elapsed time and display result
            timer = clock() - timer;
            cout << bids.size() << " bids loaded" << endl;
            cout << "time: " << (float)timer/CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000  << "   milliseconds" << endl;
            cout << "time: " << (float)timer/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;

            break;
        case 3:
            // FIXME (6): Loop and display the bids read
            for (int i = 0; i < bids.size(); ++i)
            {

                displayBid(bids[i]);

            }
            cout << endl;

            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "Good bye." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How is the displayBid function taking in a Vector as a parameter when it is supposed to take in a struct.

Comment: `void displayBid(Bid bid)` takes one `Bid` as a parameter. `void displayBid(std::vector<Bid> bids)` is what it would look like if it took a vector of `Bid`s.

Comment: You never call `displayBid` with a vector - you call it with single element from `bids` vector

Comment: So each element in the bids vector is a struct correct?

Comment: @RuskiCode each element is an object of type `Bid`. The keywords `struct`, `class` and `union` all introduce class types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't, you're passing a copy of i-th element of the vector of bid structs, not the entire vector.

Comment: I understand now ty. I am passing a struct that is part of a vector.

Comment: May want to note that `bid` is a *copy* of the vector element

Answer (score 0):

If I get your point ...

```
case 3:
    // FIXME (6): Loop and display the bids read
    displayBid(bids);
    cout << endl;
    break;
```

and I'd define the displayBid something like:

```
void displayBid(std::vector<Bid> &bids)
{
    for_each(begin(bids), end(bids), [](Bid& b) {
        cout << b.title << " | " << b.amount << " | " << b.fund << endl;
    });
}
```

if you cannot change the displayBid you can create an helper method ... something like this:

```
void displayBids(std::vector<Bid> &bids)
{
    for_each(begin(bids), end(bids), [](Bid& b) {displayBid(b)});
}
```

not tested code ... you need a couple of includes (e.g.: algorithm, etc ) ...

Comment: You don't need to wrap a free function in a lambda to pass it to `for_each`, `for_each(begin(bids), end(bids), displayBid);` works fine

Comment: that's right @Caleth