# Printing Clock Ticks and Seconds after sorting Bid Vector using Selection Sort Algorithm

Tags: c++, selection-sort

I am trying to print out the correct number of clock ticks and seconds after extracting data from a CVS file and then sorting the bid vector using the Selection Sort algorithm. Whenever I select option 1 to call the loadBids function, it prints:

12023 bids read

time: 1836 clock ticks

time: 1.836 seconds

Whenever I select option 3 to call the sortSelection function, it prints:

12023 bids sorted

time: 2520 clock ticks

time: 2.52 seconds

Option 1 should be printing numbers close to:

12023 bids read

time: 12023 clock ticks

time: 0.173945 seconds

Option 3 should be printing numbers close to:

12023 bids sorted

time: 10623604 clock ticks

time: 10.6236 seconds

Can someone help me with this? Here is my code:

VectorSorting.cpp

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

#include "CSVparser.hpp"

using namespace std;

//============================================================================
// Global definitions visible to all methods and classes
//============================================================================

// forward declarations
double strToDouble(string str, char ch);

// define a structure to hold bid information
struct Bid {
   string bidId; // unique identifier
   string title;
   string fund;
   double amount;
   Bid() {
       amount = 0.0;
   }
};

//============================================================================
// Static methods used for testing
//============================================================================

/**
 * Display the bid information to the console (std::out)
*
* @param bid struct containing the bid info
*/
void displayBid(Bid bid) {
    cout << bid.bidId << ": " << bid.title << " | " << bid.amount << " | "
            << bid.fund << endl;
    return;
}

/**
* Prompt user for bid information using console (std::in)
 *
* @return Bid struct containing the bid info
*/
Bid getBid() {
    Bid bid;

    cout << "Enter Id: ";
   cin.ignore();
   getline(cin, bid.bidId);

   cout << "Enter title: ";
   getline(cin, bid.title);

   cout << "Enter fund: ";
   cin >> bid.fund;

   cout << "Enter amount: ";
   cin.ignore();
   string strAmount;
   getline(cin, strAmount);
   bid.amount = strToDouble(strAmount, '$');

   return bid;
 }

/**
* Load a CSV file containing bids into a container
*
* @param csvPath the path to the CSV file to load
* @return a container holding all the bids read
*/
vector<Bid> loadBids(string csvPath) {
    cout << "Loading CSV file " << csvPath << endl;

   // Define a vector data structure to hold a collection of bids.
   vector<Bid> bids;

   // initialize the CSV Parser using the given path
   csv::Parser file = csv::Parser(csvPath);

    try {
        // loop to read rows of a CSV file
        for (int i = 0; i < file.rowCount(); i++) {

        // Create a data structure and add to the collection of bids
        Bid bid;
        bid.bidId = file[i][1];
        bid.title = file[i][0];
        bid.fund = file[i][8];
        bid.amount = strToDouble(file[i][4], '$');

        //cout << "Item: " << bid.title << ", Fund: " << bid.fund << ", Amount: " << 
  bid.amount << endl;

        // push this bid to the end
        bids.push_back(bid);
    }
  } catch (csv::Error &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return bids;
}

// FIXME (2a): Implement the quick sort logic over bid.title

/**
 * Partition the vector of bids into two parts, low and high
 *
 * @param bids Address of the vector<Bid> instance to be partitioned
 * @param begin Beginning index to partition
 * @param end Ending index to partition
 */
int partition(vector<Bid>& bids, int begin, int end) {
    //set low and high equal to begin and end
    int low = begin;
    int high = end;
    // pick the middle element as pivot point
    int pivot = (begin + (end - begin) / 2);
    // while not done 
    bool done = false;
    while (bids[low].title.compare(bids[pivot].title) < 0) {
    // keep incrementing low index while bids[low] < bids[pivot]
    ++low;
    }  
    // keep decrementing high index while bids[pivot] < bids[high]
    while (bids[pivot].title.compare(bids[high].title) < 0) {
      --high;
    }    

    /* If there are zero or one elements remaining,
        all bids are partitioned. Return high */
   // else swap the low and high bids (built in vector method)
        // move low and high closer ++low, --high
   //return high;
   if (low >= high) {
       done = true;
   }
   else {
       swap(bids[low], bids[high]);
       ++low;
       --high;
   }

   return high;
 }

/**
* Perform a quick sort on bid title
* Average performance: O(n log(n))
* Worst case performance O(n^2))
*
* @param bids address of the vector<Bid> instance to be sorted
* @param begin the beginning index to sort on
* @param end the ending index to sort on
*/
 void quickSort(vector<Bid>& bids, int begin, int end) {
     //set mid equal to 0

    /* Base case: If there are 1 or zero bids to sort,
     partition is already sorted otherwise if begin is greater
     than or equal to end then return*/

    /* Partition bids into low and high such that
    midpoint is location of last element in low */
 
    // recursively sort low partition (begin to mid)

    // recursively sort high partition (mid+1 to end)

}

// FIXME (1a): Implement the selection sort logic over bid.title

/**
* Perform a selection sort on bid title
* Average performance: O(n^2))
* Worst case performance O(n^2))
*
* @param bid address of the vector<Bid>
*            instance to be sorted
*/
 void selectionSort(vector<Bid>& bids) {
 //define min as int (index of the current minimum bid)
 int i, min;

// check size of bids vector
// set size_t platform-neutral result equal to bid.size()
size_t platform = bids.size();
// pos is the position within bids that divides sorted/unsorted
// for size_t pos = 0 and less than size -1 
for (size_t pos = 0;pos < platform - 1; pos++) {
    // set min = pos
    min = pos;
    // loop over remaining elements to the right of position
    for (i=pos+1;i < platform; i++) {
        // if this element's title is less than minimum title
        if (&bids[i] < &bids[min]) {
            // this element becomes the minimum
            min = i;
        }
    }
    if (min != pos) {
        // swap the current minimum with smaller one found
        // swap is a built in vector method
        swap(bids[pos], bids[min]);
    }          
   
  }

}

/**
* Simple C function to convert a string to a double
 * after stripping out unwanted char
 *
 * credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24875936
 *
 * @param ch The character to strip out
 */
double strToDouble(string str, char ch) {
   str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ch), str.end());
   return atof(str.c_str());
}

/**
* The one and only main() method
*/
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

// process command line arguments
string csvPath;
switch (argc) {
case 2:
    csvPath = argv[1];
    break;
default:
    csvPath = "eBid_Monthly_Sales.csv";
}

// Define a vector to hold all the bids
vector<Bid> bids;

// Define a timer variable
clock_t ticks;

int choice = 0;
while (choice != 9) {
    cout << "Menu:" << endl;
    cout << "  1. Load Bids" << endl;
    cout << "  2. Display All Bids" << endl;
    cout << "  3. Selection Sort All Bids" << endl;
    cout << "  4. Quick Sort All Bids" << endl;
    cout << "  9. Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Enter choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice) {

    case 1:
        // Initialize a timer variable before loading bids
        ticks = clock();

        // Complete the method call to load the bids
        bids = loadBids(csvPath);

        cout << bids.size() << " bids read" << endl;

        // Calculate elapsed time and display result
        ticks = clock() - ticks; // current clock ticks minus starting clock ticks
        cout << "time: " << ticks << " clock ticks" << endl;
        cout << "time: " << ticks * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;

        break;

    case 2:
        // Loop and display the bids read
        for (int i = 0; i < bids.size(); ++i) {
            displayBid(bids[i]);
        }
        cout << endl;

        break;

    
    case 3:
        // Initialize a timer variable before loading bids
        ticks = clock();

        bids = loadBids(csvPath);

        // FIXME (1b): Invoke the selection sort and report timing results
        selectionSort(bids);

        cout << bids.size() << " bids sorted" << endl;

        // Calculate elapsed time and display result
        ticks = clock() - ticks; // current clock ticks minus starting clock ticks
        cout << "time: " << ticks << " clock ticks" << endl;
        cout << "time: " << (ticks * 1.0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;

        break;

    // FIXME (2b): Invoke the quick sort and report timing results

    }
}

cout << "Good bye." << endl;

return 0;
}
```

CSVparser.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "CSVparser.hpp"

namespace csv {

Parser::Parser(const std::string &data, const DataType &type, char 
sep)
: _type(type), _sep(sep)
{
  std::string line;
  if (type == eFILE)
  {
    _file = data;
    std::ifstream ifile(_file.c_str());
    if (ifile.is_open())
    {
        while (ifile.good())
        {
            getline(ifile, line);
            if (line != "")
                _originalFile.push_back(line);
        }
        ifile.close();

        if (_originalFile.size() == 0)
          throw Error(std::string("No Data in ").append(_file));
        
        parseHeader();
        parseContent();
    }
    else
        throw Error(std::string("Failed to open ").append(_file));
  }
  else
  {
    std::istringstream stream(data);
    while (std::getline(stream, line))
      if (line != "")
        _originalFile.push_back(line);
    if (_originalFile.size() == 0)
      throw Error(std::string("No Data in pure content"));

    parseHeader();
    parseContent();
  }
  }

  Parser::~Parser(void)
  {
   std::vector<Row *>::iterator it;

   for (it = _content.begin(); it != _content.end(); it++)
      delete *it;
  }

  void Parser::parseHeader(void)
  {
  std::stringstream ss(_originalFile[0]);
  std::string item;

  while (std::getline(ss, item, _sep))
      _header.push_back(item);
}

void Parser::parseContent(void)
{
 std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
 
 it = _originalFile.begin();
 it++; // skip header

 for (; it != _originalFile.end(); it++)
 {
     bool quoted = false;
     int tokenStart = 0;
     unsigned int i = 0;

     Row *row = new Row(_header);

     for (; i != it->length(); i++)
     {
          if (it->at(i) == '"')
              quoted = ((quoted) ? (false) : (true));
          else if (it->at(i) == ',' && !quoted)
          {
              row->push(it->substr(tokenStart, i - tokenStart));
              tokenStart = i + 1;
          }
     }

     //end
     row->push(it->substr(tokenStart, it->length() - tokenStart));

     // if value(s) missing
     if (row->size() != _header.size())
      throw Error("corrupted data !");
     _content.push_back(row);
  }
 }

Row &Parser::getRow(unsigned int rowPosition) const
{
  if (rowPosition < _content.size())
      return *(_content[rowPosition]);
  throw Error("can't return this row (doesn't exist)");
}

Row &Parser::operator[](unsigned int rowPosition) const
{
  return Parser::getRow(rowPosition);
}

unsigned int Parser::rowCount(void) const
{
  return _content.size();
}

 unsigned int Parser::columnCount(void) const
{
  return _header.size();
}

 std::vector<std::string> Parser::getHeader(void) const
{
  return _header;
}

const std::string Parser::getHeaderElement(unsigned int pos) const
{
  if (pos >= _header.size())
    throw Error("can't return this header (doesn't exist)");
  return _header[pos];
}

bool Parser::deleteRow(unsigned int pos)
{
if (pos < _content.size())
{
  delete *(_content.begin() + pos);
  _content.erase(_content.begin() + pos);
  return true;
}
return false;
}

bool Parser::addRow(unsigned int pos, const 
 std::vector<std::string> &r)
{
Row *row = new Row(_header);

for (auto it = r.begin(); it != r.end(); it++)
  row->push(*it);

if (pos <= _content.size())
{
  _content.insert(_content.begin() + pos, row);
  return true;
}
return false;
}

void Parser::sync(void) const
{
if (_type == DataType::eFILE)
{
  std::ofstream f;
  f.open(_file, std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);

  // header
   unsigned int i = 0;
   for (auto it = _header.begin(); it != _header.end(); it++)
  {
    f << *it;
    if (i < _header.size() - 1)
      f << ",";
    else
      f << std::endl;
    i++;
  }
 
  for (auto it = _content.begin(); it != _content.end(); it++)
    f << **it << std::endl;
  f.close();
  }
 }

 const std::string &Parser::getFileName(void) const
 {
  return _file;    
 }

/*
** ROW
*/

Row::Row(const std::vector<std::string> &header)
  : _header(header) {}

Row::~Row(void) {}

unsigned int Row::size(void) const
{
return _values.size();
}

void Row::push(const std::string &value)
{
_values.push_back(value);
}

bool Row::set(const std::string &key, const std::string &value) 
{
 std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it;
int pos = 0;

 for (it = _header.begin(); it != _header.end(); it++)
{
    if (key == *it)
    {
      _values[pos] = value;
      return true;
    }
    pos++;
}
return false;
}

 const std::string Row::operator[](unsigned int valuePosition) const
{
   if (valuePosition < _values.size())
       return _values[valuePosition];
   throw Error("can't return this value (doesn't exist)");
  }

const std::string Row::operator[](const std::string &key) const
{
  std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it;
  int pos = 0;

   for (it = _header.begin(); it != _header.end(); it++)
  {
      if (key == *it)
          return _values[pos];
      pos++;
  }
  
  throw Error("can't return this value (doesn't exist)");
}

 std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Row &row)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i != row._values.size(); i++)
      os << row._values[i] << " | ";

  return os;
}

std::ofstream &operator<<(std::ofstream &os, const Row &row)
{
for (unsigned int i = 0; i != row._values.size(); i++)
{
    os << row._values[i];
    if (i < row._values.size() - 1)
      os << ",";
}
return os;
}
}
```

CSVparser.hpp

```
#ifndef     _CSVPARSER_HPP_
# define    _CSVPARSER_HPP_

# include <stdexcept>
# include <string>
# include <vector>
# include <list>
# include <sstream>

namespace csv
{
class Error : public std::runtime_error
{

  public:
    Error(const std::string &msg):
      std::runtime_error(std::string("CSVparser : ").append(msg))
    {
    }
 };

 class Row
 {
    public:
        Row(const std::vector<std::string> &);
        ~Row(void);

    public:
        unsigned int size(void) const;
        void push(const std::string &);
        bool set(const std::string &, const std::string &); 

    private:
        const std::vector<std::string> _header;
        std::vector<std::string> _values;

    public:

        template<typename T>
        const T getValue(unsigned int pos) const
        {
            if (pos < _values.size())
            {
                T res;
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << _values[pos];
                ss >> res;
                return res;
            }
            throw Error("can't return this value (doesn't exist)");
        }
        const std::string operator[](unsigned int) const;
        const std::string operator[](const std::string &valueName) 
const;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Row 
&row);
        friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& os, const 
Row &row);
 };

enum DataType {
    eFILE = 0,
    ePURE = 1
};

class Parser
{

public:
    Parser(const std::string &, const DataType &type = eFILE, char 
sep = ',');
    ~Parser(void);

public:
    Row &getRow(unsigned int row) const;
    unsigned int rowCount(void) const;
    unsigned int columnCount(void) const;
    std::vector<std::string> getHeader(void) const;
    const std::string getHeaderElement(unsigned int pos) const;
    const std::string &getFileName(void) const;

public:
    bool deleteRow(unsigned int row);
    bool addRow(unsigned int pos, const std::vector<std::string> 
&);
    void sync(void) const;

protected:
    void parseHeader(void);
    void parseContent(void);

private:
    std::string _file;
    const DataType _type;
    const char _sep;
    std::vector<std::string> _originalFile;
    std::vector<std::string> _header;
    std::vector<Row *> _content;

public:
    Row &operator[](unsigned int row) const;
};
}

#endif /*!_CSVPARSER_HPP_*/
```

Comment: what makes you think the results you are printing are wrong?

Comment: Because the number of clock ticks in my output from Selection Sort are way too low compared to an example number that I've seen in the guidelines

Comment: 10 seconds to sort 12k items would be incredibly slow, even for a terrible algorithm